# JavaScript framework and architecture for server side rendered html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frameworks

How can I use a model centric JavaScript MV-Whatever Framework like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) that renders on server side to improve page load and assists on SEO.  I like AngularJS, especially the data binding, but it seems not to be the best fit for my needs.  I want to *render a complete html* page on the server to minimize the time until the page is visible to the user. This would also allow search engines to crawl the site. The rendered page should then be *made dynamic by JavaScript*. It should *communicate asynchronously* with the server to update the model and the view, once the page is loaded. The application should work on usual *desktop computers and on mobile devices*.

**Why not jQuery?** This sounds like the jQuery approach: render html, query and manipulate the DOM. But jQuery is not centered around a model and jQuery code tends to be somewhat [unstructured](http://blog.coderstats.net/todomvc-complexity/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) and unnecessary complex.

**jQuery + AngularJS?** Would it be a good idea to render a complete html page, extract a model from the DOM with jQuery and give this model to AngularJS to act on it for the rest of the time. This would allow to use the structured AngularJS approach and the nice data binding.

**Other frameworks?** I've heard that [twitter switched from a pure JavaScript client back to a html-first approach](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-twittercom). As far as I know twitter uses [Flight](http://twitter.github.io/flight/), but I don't understand their whole client-side architecture based on this framework yet. Flight by itself seems to be nothing but a kind of a message bus.

**What approach or framework would you suggest?**

Comment: Completely offtopic question, but have you seen [Render from Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr)? It was made to solve the exact problems you are facing. Uses Backbone + Node.js.

Comment: Just a note. You can make dynamic pages (with AJAX content) crawlable by search engines. It does not as easy as with a static site, but it works just fine once you get it in place.